# O(1) indexable deque of integers in Python

Tags: python, collections

what are my options there? I need to call a lot of `append`s (to the right end) and `popleft`s (from the left end, naturally), but also to read from the middle of the storage, which will steadily grow, by the nature of the algorithm. I would like to have all these operations in `O(1)`.

I could implement it in C easy enough on circularly-addressed array (what's the word?) which would grow automatically when it's full; but what about Python? Pointers to other languages are appreciated too (I realize the "collections" tag is more Java etc. oriented and would appreciate the comparison, but as a secondary goal).

I come from a Lisp background and was amazed to learn that in Python removing a head element from a list is an `O(n)` operation. A `deque` could be an answer except the documentation says access is `O(n)` in the middle. Is there anything else, pre-built?

Comment: in general, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree might be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an amortized O(1) data structure by using two python lists, one holding the left half of the deque and the other holding the right half. The front half is stored reversed so the left end of the deque is at the back of the list. Something like this:

```
class mydeque(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.left = []
    self.right = []

  def pushleft(self, v):
    self.left.append(v)

  def pushright(self, v):
    self.right.append(v)

  def popleft(self):
    if not self.left:
      self.__fill_left()
    return self.left.pop()

  def popright(self):
    if not self.right:
      self.__fill_right()
    return self.right.pop()

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.left) + len(self.right)

  def __getitem__(self, i):
    if i >= len(self.left):
      return self.right[i-len(self.left)]
    else:
      return self.left[-(i+1)]

  def __fill_right(self):
    x = len(self.left)//2
    self.right.extend(self.left[0:x])
    self.right.reverse()
    del self.left[0:x]

  def __fill_left(self):
    x = len(self.right)//2
    self.left.extend(self.right[0:x])
    self.left.reverse()
    del self.right[0:x]
```

I'm not 100% sure if the interaction between this code and the amortized performance of python's lists actually result in O(1) for each operation, but my gut says so.

Comment: thanks a lot, will think about it. will `del self.right[0:x]` take O(n) time? and `extend` too?

Comment: actually, I never call `popright` and `pushleft` in this algorithm, so I'll just swap the reversed right for the left whenever the left gets exhausted. This is excellent! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that `fill_right` and `fill_left` are called only every O(n) operations so that each operation takes amortized O(1) time. I'm pretty sure what you ask is only possible in amortized O(1) time unless the size is bounded (the resize you mention in the Q for a C implementation will make it O(n) worst case too).

Comment: yes, I understand this, occasional O(n) is good (but worse than O(n) wouldn't be, is what I meant). Sorry for being unclear. But since I never call `popright` and `pushleft` the only one that gets ever exhausted is `left` and I'll just use the reversed `right` for it! I'll just use these two lists interchangeably in the code directly. Thank you very much!

Comment: The code `q = mydeque();
q.pushleft(1);
print(q.popright())
` crashes because the `__fill_left` function only transfer `1 // 2 == 0` elements from the "left" list to the "right" list.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the middle of a lisp list is also O(n).

Python `list`s are array lists, which is why popping the head is expensive (popping the tail is constant time).

What you are looking for is an array with (amortised) constant time deletions at the head; that basically means that you are going to have to build a datastructure on top of `list` that uses lazy deletion, and is able to recycle lazily-deleted slots when the queue is empty.

Alternatively, use a hashtable, and a couple of integers to keep track of the current contiguous range of keys.

Comment: can I remove a contiguous range from the head of a list in O(n) time? How?

Comment: @WillNess And yet...python programmers still use hashtables. If you're trying to look up hashtables under 'H', then I suggest that you follow a tutorial (or peruse the documentation) to learn about what python has to offer.

Comment: @WillNess If you don't know how to delete part of a list then I *definitely* suggest that you follow a python tutorial.

Comment: I though I was trying to do just that - to find it in the documentation.

Comment: @WillNess Don't just search the documentation. Read it.

Comment: @WillNess, I'll give you a hint: dictionaries. And Marcin, you could be a little more helpful.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am being helpful. What I am not doing is enabling continued laziness.

Comment: @WillNess You haven't bothered to learn the syntax for working with basic types, or even learned what built-in datatypes exist. The answer to both of your questions posed on this answer is to actually learn python using either standard documentation or introductory materials.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, will look into it. In the meantime the other answer gave me an algorithmic idea that solves this. Thanks again.

Comment: you've misread my question in the comments. I haven't asked you how can contiguous range be removed from the head of the list. I asked you whether and how can it be done in O(n) time. So it wasn't a syntax question. Documentation gives no performance guarantees. And yes I'm unfamiliar with all the built-in types of Python, that is what my question asks - whether there is a built in type like that. Sending me on the wild goose chase reading tutorials is not helpful when all I asked for were some pointers for me to explore further. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @WillNess Actually, if you understood the documentation, you would understand that deletion at the head occurs in O(n) time. I'm not sending you on a wild goose chase, I'm sending you to the place which has the information you need. If you can't be bothered to learn python, I see no reason why I should try to teach you one drib of information at a time.

Comment: the docs does not discuss efficiency, nor implementation. what should i have understood, my own wild guesses about it? nothing precludes an implementation with O(1) block removal at head of list. or maybe it is quadratic? what *is* ["slow"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues)?? who knows!.. how dare I ask! For instance, as hard I searched in the docs, I couldn't find performance guarantees for dictionaries. But I'm too afraid to ask now.

Answer (score 0):

[Python's Queue Module](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue) may help you, although I'm not sure if access is `O(1)`.

Comment: Queue does not support access to the middle of the queue.